# Convert hh:mm:ss in BIDS to numeric seconds

Tags: time, bids, ssis-2008

I'm importing data from a csv using BIDS [SQL Server 2008r2]. I need to convert hh:mm:ss to numeric to be imported into SQL Server. For example

00:01:05 = 65

Current Steps:

[image]

The conversion looks like this. 
[image: DataConversion]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the assumption that you are talking about SQL Server Integration Services, you can accomplish this via a Derived Column Transformation.

Drag a [Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx) into your data flow pipeline, and connect the source.

[image]

Open it up and add a new field, giving it a name and selecting `<add as new column>`.  Paste the following formula into the Expression box, replacing 'SrcTime' with the name of your field: this expression will convert the time field into decimal minutes (e.g., 01:01:30 becomes 61.5)

```
(DT_NUMERIC,6,2)(((DT_I4)LEFT(SrcTime,2) * 60) + 
((DT_I4)SUBSTRING(SrcTime,4,2)) + 
((DT_NUMERIC,4,2)RIGHT(SrcTime,2) / 60))
```

EDIT: if you need it in seconds, not minutes (01:01:30 becomes 3690.00), you could alter the formula to be:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)(((DT_I4)LEFT(SrcTime,2) * 3600) + 
((DT_I4)SUBSTRING(SrcTime,4,2) * 60 ) + 
((DT_NUMERIC,4,2)RIGHT(SrcTime,2)))
```

EDIT AGAIN: Based on your version, the `LEFT()` function is not available in the Expression Editor.  Use this formula instead:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)(((DT_I4)SUBSTRING([TALK TIME],1,2) * 3600) + 
((DT_I4)SUBSTRING([TALK TIME],4,2) * 60) + 
((DT_NUMERIC,4,2)RIGHT([TALK TIME],2)))
```

[image]
This will add a new column to your pipeline, with the name you gave it in 'Derived Column Name', which will have the correct format.

Comment: Mine doesn't have a LEFT function. I have RIGHT, but not LEFT.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2008r2

Comment: OK so building off your answer, and not having access to the LEFT function, does this look right?
(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)(((DT_I4)SUBSTRING([TALK TIME],1,2) * 3600) + ((DT_I4)SUBSTRING([TALK TIME],4,2) * 60) + ((DT_NUMERIC,4,2)RIGHT([TALK TIME],2)))

Comment: That looks perfect!  `LEFT()` was added for 2012 (I think), so your `SUBSTRING()` is the correct one.  Try it out and let me know if it works - I'll update my answer to include the correct function for your version.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be attained by converting string datatype in timestamp. and then using following expression in derived column expression:

DatePart("Hh",[Talk Time])*3600 + DatePart("mi",[Talk time])*60 + DatePart("ss",[Talk Time])

The above expression will return numeric data in number